# Equivalent of %02d with std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, formatting, stringstream

I want to output an integer to a `std::stringstream` with the equivalent format of `printf`'s `%02d`. Is there an easier way to achieve this than:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream.setfill('0');
stream.setw(2);
stream << value;
```

Is it possible to stream some sort of format flags to the `stringstream`, something like (pseudocode):

```
stream << flags("%02d") << value;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `stream.fill('0')` and `stream.width(2)` ?  You are using the name of the manipulators almost like you know the answer to your own question?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use the standard manipulators from `<iomanip>` but there isn't a neat one that does both `fill` and `width` at once:

```
stream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << value;
```

It wouldn't be hard to write your own object that when inserted into the stream performed both functions:

```
stream << myfillandw( '0', 2 ) << value;
```

E.g.

```
struct myfillandw
{
    myfillandw( char f, int w )
        : fill(f), width(w) {}

    char fill;
    int width;
};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const myfillandw& a )
{
    o.fill( a.fill );
    o.width( a.width );
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
stream<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<value;
```

Answer (score 11):

You can't do that much better in standard C++. Alternatively, you can use Boost.Format:

```
stream << boost::format("%|02|")%value;
```

Comment: And if you are not using the `stream` for anything else, you don't need it, because `boost::format` already produces a string.

Comment: I heard you have to pass it to `str(...)` then

Comment: Jahonnes you can use std::string myStr = (boost::format("%|02|")%value).str();

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to stream some sort of format flags to the `stringstream`?

Unfortunately the standard library doesn't support passing format specifiers as a string, but you can do this with the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt):

```
std::string result = fmt::format("{:02}", value); // Python syntax
```

or

```
std::string result = fmt::sprintf("%02d", value); // printf syntax
```

You don't even need to construct `std::stringstream`. The `format` function will return a string directly.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).

Answer (score 0):

i think you can  use c-lick programing.

you can use `snprintf`

like this

```
std::stringstream ss;
 char data[3] = {0};
 snprintf(data,3,"%02d",value);
 ss<<data<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use such function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <cstdio>

const char * sformat(const char * fmt, ...)
{
    static char buffer[4][512]; // nesting less than 4x, length less then 512
    static int i = -1;
    if(++i > 3) i = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    std::vsnprintf(buffer[i], 511, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return buffer[i];
}
```