# c++ custom string format using stringstreams

Tags: c++, string-formatting

I am trying to use the new stringstreams method to convert certain float+int combination into certain format but trying to see if there is any better way to handle this:

Now using //string String = static_cast( &(ostringstream() << Number) )->str();  kind of mode - How can I get this stored into a string form of the format - "1.10(3)". Precision is equal to decimals. The catch here is none of these values are constants.  Even if the solution can't be an in-line function or stringstreams - it's fine as long as it's generic enough. Also note that in the end the plan is to use this string into GDI text string.

Thanks in advance - if any one can help.

Here is my current sample code(and looking for an alternate efficient way to get this done):

```
string Convert(float number,int decimals)
{
std::ostringstream buff;
buff<<setprecision(decimals)<<fixed<<number;
return buff.str();
}


float f=1.1;     // this can have any values from 1,1.5 or 1.52
int decimals=2;  //dynamic number - calculated by other means - not a fixed number
int i=3;         // some dynamic number as well - calculated by other means

string s=Convert(f,decimals)+"("+Convert(i,0)+")";  // output - 1.10(3)
```

Comment: Related / dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839592/equivalent-of-02d-with-stdstringstream

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/), [`std::setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/), [`std::setw`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) and [`std::setfill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/) defined in [`<iomanip>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/) :

```
float f=1.1;  
int decimals=2;
int i=3;
ostringstream ss;
ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(decimals) << f << '(' << i << ')';
string str = ss.str();
```

Which outputs :

```
1.10(3)
```

You can also configure the stringstream and keep this configuration :

```
ostringstream ss;
ss.precision(5);
ss.setf(std::ios::fixed);
```

**EDIT**

You can still do this in one line if you **really** want to :

```
string str = ((ostringstream&)(ostringstream() << fixed << setprecision(decimals) << f << '(' << i << ')')).str();
```

If you want a `LPCWSTR` (`const wchar_t *`) instead of a `LPCSTR` (`const char*`)  you should use `wstringstream` instead of `stringstream`.

```
ostringstream ss;
string str = ss.str();
LPCSTR* c_str = str.c_str();

wostringstream wss;
wstring wstr = wss.str();
LPCWSTR* wc_str = wstr.c_str();
```

If you want a `LPCTSTR` (`LPCSTR` or `LPCWSTR` if `UNICODE` is defined), you can use some `typedef` like this :

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
typedef std::basic_ostringstream<TCHAR , std::char_traits<TCHAR> > tstringstream;

tostringstream tss;
tstring tstr = tss.str();
LPCTSTR* tc_str = tstr.c_str();
```

TCHAR is a `char *` if `UNICODE` is not defined in your project and a `wchar_t *` if `UNICODE` is defined.

Comment: zakinster - thanks - but here you are hard-coding "2" for setw(2). Wanted to avoid that hard-coded value there.

Comment: @ejuset ok you didn't specify in your first post that you were looking for an alternative to this approach.

Comment: Thanks @zakinster - Perfect.. Though could have been better with some kind of "complex" static_cast to make it into a one-liner.. but this is definitely better than what I have as a convert function.. Thanks.

Comment: @ejuser you can still do this in one line but it's not pretty (see my last edit).

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you !! I like the one liner - you have ( leaving aside the the content of the line - code would be much more readable due to less number of lines:)

Comment: You also got me thinking about - ss.setf(std::ios::fixed); --> seems like an efficient way to do it..have to think more about this.. Thanks for the tip as well.

Comment: zakinster - Instead of string - can this be made as "LPCSTR" - which seems to be what is needed for DrawText method.
at present - I use another function to convert this to LPCSTR:
    wstring(str.begin(),str.end()).c_str()   from the above string. If there is a direct conversion to this LPCSTR - it would be more efficient for what I am trying to do.. Thanks

Comment: `LPCSTR` is the Win32 API name for `const char*`, no conversion needed from `string.c_str()`. If you use wstring it would give you a `LPCWSTR` which is a `const wchar_t *`. If you want a `wstring` from the `stringstream` you should use `wostringstream` instead of `ostringstream`.

Comment: `DrawText`take a `LPCTSTR` which is either `LPCSTR` or `LPCWSTR`depending on your compiler configuration.

Comment: I am testing out - these options and would post back with comments. Thank you for your help on this matter.

Comment: - At present I ended up this way - and direct "wostring" mode of cast doesn't seem to be working..
        string str = ((ostringstream&)(ostringstream() << fixed << setprecision(decimals) << f << '(' << i << ')')).str();

in the DrawText - using the following conversion functions along with above line:
    str.c_str()
    str.length()

Comment: Found one useful link in this context as I continued to get weird issues between compilers with WinAPI - Visual studio / gcc compilers.. related to Unicode setting..
[ http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/16820/ ]