# How to achieve the maximum field width feature of sscanf via istringstream in C++?

Tags: c++, scanf, istringstream, formatted-input

I know it is possible to use `istringstream` as an alternative to `sscanf`, for example:

```
std::istringstream argtime{"01:00"};
char colon;
int hour;
int minute;

argtime >> std::noskipws;
argtime >> hour >> colon >> minute;
if(argtime && colon == ':') // hh:mm is parsed successfully.
{
    // ...
}
```

The above lines are partly similar to the following `sscanf` code:

```
sscanf("01:00", "%d:%d", &hour, &minute);
```

But is there any solution to achieve *the maximum field width* feature of `sscanf` via `istringstream` in C++ (C++11/C++14/C++1z)?

```
sscanf("01:00", "%2d:%2d", &hour, &minute);
```

Edit: I also tried `setw` IO manipulator, but it does not work for integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839592/equivalent-of-02d-with-stdstringstream

Comment: @A.S.H: No, it is not. I'm asking about Input Stream.

Comment: That's why I said ""Possible". To suggest you check that thread, iy might answer your question since there is much similarity in formatting stremas for input and for output. You might also have the limitations discussed there.