# How to convert various data types into one wchar_t?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have got

```
int MyReader::getInfo(wchar_t &o_Info)
{
    // some code

    MyInfo* m_pSegment = pData->getSegmentPtr();
    if (!m_pSegment)
        return(MY_ERR); 
    
    uint32 o_Id32g; // unsigned int
    uint16 o_Id16g[2]; // unsigned short[2]
    uint8 o_Id8g[8]; // unsigned char[8]
    
    m_pSegment->get(o_Id32g, o_Id16g, o_Id8g);

    // how to convert o_Id32g, o_Id16g, o_Id8g to one wchar_t &o_Info???

    return(MY_OK);
}
```

where

```
void MyInfo::get(uint32 &o_Id32, uint16 o_Id16[2], uint8 o_Id8[8])
{
    o_Id32 = m_Id32;
    if(o_Id16)
        ::memcpy(o_Id16, m_Id16, sizeof(m_Id16));
    if(o_Id8)
        ::memcpy(o_Id8, m_Id8, sizeof(m_Id8));
}
```

How to convert now all `o_Id32g`, `o_Id16g`, `o_Id8g` values into one `wchar_t` object? I am new in C++, I probably miss bigger picture. Should I count all digits, then allocate required memory for `wchar_t &o_Info` and than somehow add digits to `&o_Info` in a loop?

Values from getter might look like:

```
m_Id16  0x000001d98dbc08a0 {12345, 0123}    unsigned short[2]
m_Id32  9999999999  unsigned int
m_Id8   0x000001d98dbc08a8 "€"  unsigned char[8]
[0] 128 '€' unsigned char
[1] 0 '\0'  unsigned char
[2] 174 '®' unsigned char
[3] 201 'É' unsigned char
[4] 59 ';'  unsigned char
[5] 189 '½' unsigned char
[6] 155 '›' unsigned char
[7] 0 '\0'  unsigned char
```

so desired outcome is `"1234501239999999999€\0®É;½›\0"`

Comment: What was the topic of your C++ class, or the chapter in your C++ textbook where this practice problem came from? This will help in pointing you at the correct approach that you're expected to learn from your class, or textbook. There are several different possible C++ topics that this kind of a problem is designed to cover, so we need to know exactly what you're supposed to learn from doing this practice problem, in order not to waste your time with something irrelevant.

Comment: Hi @SamVarshavchik, thanks for the comment! I am at work, not at school ;) We do read a files, `MyInfo` class was already implemented long time ago and we can read those mixed values for a long time. They were just not needed until now. Now I need to pass them further, but one `wchar_t` object would be just fine. I would like to get some good hint, learn good practice how to manage this.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. If it's the logic described in the end of your question: concatenate as strings two 16bit integers, one 32bit integer and eight 8bit characters, then [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2839616/4165552). Of course your `getInfo(wchar_t &o_Info)` signature is not suitable for that, because you cannot fit that much data into one `wchar_t`, which is usually 2 or 4 bytes. So, better go for `std::string getInfo();`.

Comment: wchar_t has not a fixed size, it depends on what compiler/os you are running. 
anyway it is usually 16-32 bit long so you can't store a 8bytes long char array on a 2/4 bytes long data type. You might use an array of wchar_t to achieve it, but you have to change the signature of your getter function.